# Obtaining more values from `NDEigenvalues`

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

When I run this code

```
diskLevels = 
  NDEigenvalues[
                {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
                DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
                u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 1000
         ];
```

Mathematica objects that it can only supply me with 961 eigenvalues:

```
NDEigenvalues::maxeigen: A maximum number of 961 eigenvalues and functions can be computed for this discretized system.
```

Is there a way to get more values? I tried messing around with some options but any time I managed to prevent the error message the calculation would not terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(diskLevels = NDEigenvalues[
     {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},
     u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 1000,
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" ->
        {"FiniteElement",
         "MeshOptions" ->
          {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0075}}}];) //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.657356, Null} *)

Length@diskLevels

(* 1000 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I would note: the levels returned by this code may not be reliable. If you plot the differences here then they will not be distributed as $P \sim e^{(-s)}.$ But making `MaxCellMeasure` even smaller recovers the true behavior, although at a much longer time.